# Visual Studio not using correct android sdk path

Tags: android, cordova, tfs, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

Using Visual Studio 2015, I'm trying to run a cordova hybrid app on an android device, the issue is Visual Studio is looking for the Android SDK in the wrong location.

I have the correct path set, i can build and run a hello world just fine, but it seems that when I put this project in Visual Studio Team Services things are getting weird.

This is the path it is looking for the SDK:

```
'C:\Project\MYAPP.Mobile\Source\ClientApp\MYAPP\platforms\android\Users\ME\Library\Android\sdk' does not exist.
```

It's as if it is concatenating two different directories to find the SDK. I have tried selecting the override for 'Environment Variable Overrides' for 'Tools for Apache Cordova' but it does not do anything.

Anyone get this error?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cordova cache under `tools->options->tools for apache cordova->Clear cordova cache` and run a new blank app?

Comment: I ran a new app, and copied all my logic and it compiles and runs. So it is an issue with that particular solution OR TFS is messing it up. Also tried clearing the cache on the problem solution with no luck. Do you know of a setting that would cause the weird SDK path ? Seems two different paths are being concatenated

Comment: Are you using the [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs) or Team Foundation Server on-premises?

Comment: Visual Studio Team Services, edited the question to fix that

Comment: I tried building a Cordova app through VS-TS. But no error occurs. Could you share this project through online repository( after deleting secret parts)? I'll see if I can reproduce this problem by my side.

Comment: sure, can you get me your email in a PM and i can work out getting you enough to see the error

Comment: You can send to this Email: xiaxucheng@gmail.com.